# How can I combine menu animation and button animations in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a canvas with an animator that animates the transition between different menu items.  I also have buttons (nested in canvas) whose position and size are animated by canvas.  And each button has its own animator with the animation "pressed" (resizing and rotation).  **The problem is that the button click animation has the wrong look.**  The button does not change its size and rotates a smaller degree.  *I think the point is in the "weight" of the animation*, since canvas animates the same button.  But I have no idea how to fix it ...

[1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b77IM.png)
[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8FQK.png)

Comment: I think it would be better if you attach some pictures of your work to better understand your problem and can you show us some screenshots?

Comment: @Chestera ok. I will attach them soon